# A word for not being too formal or restricted

Tags: word-usage

I wrote:

> I like Persian Shekaste Nastaliq script because it is very free and wild.

By ***wild*** I tried to mean it is not much formal and restricted and one can do more innovation in the place of the letters, points, etc. However, it yet obey some rules.Is my usage correct? What other words can I use?

Some samples:
https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/327707310362629195/

https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/132504414010624889/

https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/224476362652861524/

Comment: How about '_flexible_'?

Comment: Or even *loose*, although you might have to qualify that, like "loose in terms of what is permitted or restricted".

Answer (score 1):

*Wild* if describing the appearance of text - without other context which you may be providing - IMHO would evaluate to something like barely-legible-but-nice-looking street art or text meant to look like an animal somehow.

- An opposite of *formal* is *casual*.
- *Playful* is more informal than *casual* and would describe something that is testing boundaries a little, but still being friendly.  *Adventurous* might work too.
- Something that works in many different situations is *versatile*
- Something that doesn't have a lot of rules or regulations can be considered *liberal*.